# Loading templates in Django doesn't work

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a project that has 3 apps: app1, app2 and app3. In the first two apps I had different templates:
`app1/templates/app1/page.html`

`app2/templates/app2/anotherpage.html`

And I load them like this:

```
return render(request, "app1/page.html")
```

It worked perfectly, but now I added app3, and I tried to do the same:

`app3/templates/app3/config.html`

but when I return `app3/config.html` I get the error `TemplateDoesNotExist`

I simply created the app doing `python manage.py startapp app3` and copy the files to the folder. I also added the app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list. However, this works:

`app1/templates/app3/config.html`

`app2/templates/app3/config.html`

Why it's not working now?

Comment: Did you add the app to your list of installed_apps in the settings?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Triple-check your filename and directory spelling. Seems like this should work. It may help if you can provide the output of the `tree` command (`tree /F` on Windowze) for your project directory.

Comment: update your question to include you templates settings in settings.py